# Why images in OpenCart 3 do not load via admin panel?

Tags: php, image, content-management-system, opencart

The problem is that image uploads on a webserver without issues (chmod and chown on image and cache is ok), but sometimes they just do not appear in the admin panel. (No errors are shown, there is a message about successful upload). I can upload them only via server now. What could be wrong? Thanks.

Comment: check your browser console for error. and also check the response of ajax URL of image manage in the browser inspector network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I can assume that you sometimes have Cyrillic symbols or other special characters in image names. Some versions of OpenCart, like ocStore may have translate cyrillic into latin, but I'm not sure about all versions. For the best experience use `a-z`, `0-9`, `-` and `_` in image names.
2. Could be that images has too big resolution. Better to upload images not more than 1920px by the largest side.